# Will the extra zombie maps for Black Ops be made available in the PlayStation Store?

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-black-ops

Since the normal copy of Black Ops will only give you 3 Zombie maps, is there any chance of the extra zombie maps coming to sale to the PlayStation Store or perhaps free download?

Need to know about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to get the previous Call of Duty World at War zombie maps was to pre-order the Hardened or Prestige edition of the Call of Duty Black Ops

The extra zombie maps are now available with the last Black Ops DLC.  It also comes with a new zombie map, Moon.

http://www.callofduty.com/blackops/dlc4/rezurrection-zombies-trailer

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, details of the inevitable DLC have yet to be announced and it would be inappropriate to speculate here. However, we can take a look at Treyarch's previous Call of Duty title to give us an indication of what is to come.

There were three map packs released for World at War, each of which contained three conventional multiplayer maps and one Nazi Zombies map. The zombie maps included new weapons and weapon upgrades and also new gameplay mechanics such as telportaion. They were released approximately four, seven and nine months after the game's initial release. There was also a free map that added a new take (daylight) on an existing map. On PS3 these map packs cost €9.99/$9.99US/£7.99GBP.

Activision's CFO has [claimed](http://gamasutra.com/view/news/31490/Activisions_Tippl_Call_Of_Duty_Black_Ops_Ge) that 2011 will herald their "largest digital offering ever" in support of Black Ops. You should also be aware that Activision [have committed](http://www.cinemablend.com/games/E3-2009-Xbox-360-Gets-Exclusive-Modern-Warfare-2-DLC-17888.html) to release all of their DLC exclusively for Xbox 360 for a limited time.

The Hardened and Prestige editions of Black Ops featured a code permitting the download of all four World at War zombie maps. If this is something you missed out on, you might consider buying one from [eBay](http://shop.ebay.com/i.html?_nkw=black+ops+ps3+zombie+maps&_sacat=0&_odkw=black+ops+ps3+zombie+dlc&_osacat=0&_trksid=p3286.c0.m270.l1313).

Comment: I now see that you were specifically referring to the World at War maps. The answer is that nobody knows.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that I and a lot of others owners of the WaW zombie maps in Black Ops have made it very clear to Treyarch that we would like these maps made accessible to everyone. It doesn't make sense that only a handful of my friends have the maps and we can only play them with others who own them. This has made us not play them nearly as often as we would like to. From a business POV, it doesn't make sense for them NOT to sell them eventually too because it is free money just waiting to be made for them.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get the other maps is by buying the hardened or prestige editions. So far there is no official news about getting downloads for the other maps, but there is a rumor going around about how there will be free downloads. I'm not sure if it's true.